# Unparseable date: ""

Tags: java

Need help with parsing date(dateInString). I am new to parsing of date. 
Thanks for help

```
String dateInString = Commons.getString(row.getCell(1));
Date date = new Date();
if (!dateInString.equals("null") || !dateInString.equals("")) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
    date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
}
java.sql.Date sDate = convertUtilToSql(date);

private java.sql.Date convertUtilToSql(Date date) {
    java.sql.Date sDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
    return sDate;
}
```

[image: excel data]

Comment: That messages says the input to `parse` (i.e. `dateInString`) was an empty string.  Thus the previous line that defines `dateInString` is not returning what you expect.

Comment: Please include the input (dateInString) in your question.

Comment: @JimGarrison I tried changing the code, but getting the same error

Comment: Your answer is probably [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).  Basically, `dateInString != ""` is just _wrong_.

Comment: @ajb getting the same exception

Comment: Well, at least you fixed one problem.  But we can't help you without knowing what your input is.

Comment: @ajb I am reading excel file at column 1 for date

Comment: @Flynn1179 But it is inserting into database but getting exception at the end

Comment: You ask help for what?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `if` statement is not correct. It enters the parsing if the string context is not null or string is not empty. That looks wrong to me. The parsing should only happen if the dateString is not null AND doesn contain the value null AND is not an empty string.

So I guess that the part

```
if (!dateInString.equals("null") || !dateInString.equals("")) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
    date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
}
```

has to be changed into something like

```
if (dateString!= null && !dateInString.equals("null") && !dateInString.trim().isEmpty()) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
    date = formatter.parse(dateInString.trim());
}
```

Comment: null values are also inserting into database after modifying it

Comment: What do you mean exactly by that? The original implementation doesn't seem to do anything with null as dateString.

Comment: null values are getting inserted, when using if statement

Comment: Don't see how thy would be inserted. In your original solution date is set to current date and later converted to sql date which is probably inserted in db. Anyway, a DateString with value null would could nullpointer exception in `date = formatter.parse(dateInString.trim());` so that's why is excluded null